# How to call api in Service using HILT android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

I am using HILT for DI. I am able to network call in Activity/Fragment but unable to understand how to network call in Service.

**Below is my Application Module**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationModule::class)
class ApplicationModule {

@Provides
fun provideBaseUrl() = AppConfig.get().getBaseAPIUrl()

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideOkHttpClient() = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    loggingInterceptor.apply { loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }
    OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()
} else OkHttpClient
        .Builder()
        .build()

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, BASE_URL: String): Retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit) = retrofit.create(ApiServiceKotlin::class.java)

}
```

**Repository**

```
public class JobRemoteRepository @Inject constructor(val apiServiceKotlin: 
ApiServiceKotlin):BaseDataSource() {

suspend fun getJobDetailById(inviteId: String?) = getResult { 
apiServiceKotlin.getJobDetailById(inviteId)}
}
```

**How I can do network call in Service?**

Comment: What happens when you try the same thing you did in the activity or fragment?

Comment: it gets successfully called

Comment: add your service code